# CPU usage by app on Android 8

Tags: 8.0-oreo, overheating, cpu

My Samsung S7 is seriously overheated. Battery is being consumed super quickly. I need to see a simple list of applications with percentage of CPU usage. I am desperate because all attempts  and advices from Internet failed :( I tried:

- use `top` command on `termux`. Doesn't work. Shows only 2 processes with 0% CPU usage.
- activate the developer mode and go to `Running services`. There is no CPU usage whatsoever! Only RAM usage.
- I tried to install several recommended apps like Simple System Monitor (doesn't show the actual CPU usage of app), Legacy OS Monitor (same problem as the `top` command), System Info for Android (only shows itself in the task list!)

I don't get it. Why is it so difficult to do such an easy thing? I remember it was sooo easy on Androd 2.3!

I have Android 8.0.0. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: [It is not possible Nougat upwards](https://github.com/AntonioRedondo/AnotherMonitor#retrieving-processes-info-since-android-nougat-70-api-24-august-2016). On Oreo [it is more difficult](https://github.com/AntonioRedondo/AnotherMonitor) but if rooted [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app) claims to show - not tested

Comment: Just tested on rooted device. It works