# What to do when phone is super slow?

Tags: lagging

My Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8 is super sloooow... even happens now that it takes so much time to unlock the pattern screen that it will go black again because of the timeout... when I click into an input field, it can take 20-30 seconds before keyboard appears... it's just becoming unusable. Not always, sometimes in another part of day it happens that it's not so slow, but right now the problem persists.

How do I fix this? I tried different tools to see [what's consuming the CPU](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/197860/cpu-usage-by-app-on-android-8) but all those apps monitoring this are of no use since they are just showing themselves, probably because my device is not rooted. And I am not sure if I want to start rooting my device in this situation.

Also, my 256 GB micro SD card probably has some problems, because sometimes longer videos get corrupted. Not sure if it's related, but the situation becomes a bit complicated.

Comment: Have you adapted the SD-card as internal storage?

Comment: @Robert you mean, the external micro SD card? No, don't know about it... I just moved few apps to it. And default camera and voice rec directories.