# Samsung S7 unresponsive with blue light slightly pulsing

Tags: crashes, samsung-galaxy-s7, system-freeze, notification-led

My Samsung Galaxy S7 is completely unresponsive for day and a half, black screen, only blue LED is shining with a slight pulse. According to [this guide](https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/what-do-the-notification-light-colours-mean-on-my-samsung-galaxy-smartphone/), it means "the device is turning on or off". For a day and a half already!

So I tried this advice:

> Press and hold the “Power” and “Volume Down”
> buttons for eight to twenty seconds and the device will eventually
> turn off.

Then I tried [this advice](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/992633-galaxy-s7-wont-turn-wont-force-restart-blue-led-solid.html):

> Try pressing and holding Power and Vol Down for about 30 seconds, then
> wait a few seconds, then press and hold Power again for another 30
> seconds.

Then I tried different sequences [as advised here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LP4sD3AAWEA):

> ```
> up+power 20 secs
> down+power+home
> up+power+home
> ```

Nothing worked. Charging didn't help. Before this happened, my phone was gradually slower and slower in the last month, until it became super slow, as I [asked here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247038/what-to-do-when-phone-is-super-slow). Some time before the freeze happened, I also removed the SIM card and micro SD card from the tray. Now I put back the SIM card, the system still stuck.

PS: 10 minutes after the key combo attempts I noticed the battery and display is heated. Interesting.

PS: after 2.5 days the battery finally died and the blue light stopped pulsing. I charged it a little, but now it doesn't even turn on. No response whatsoever.

Comment: What happens if you connect the phone to a charger? Does this change anything while it is connected?

Comment: @Robert I tried that, it changed nothing. Now I am trying the opposite - **trying to starve it out of power so that it turns off physically** (because I cannot unplug the battery - where are the good old phones!). But it still holds for more than a day and half. Thanks for asking!

Comment: To drain the battery quicker, I have used a spot in my house just within reach of my neighbor's WiFi; the continued attempts to connect can speed the process.

Comment: @wbogacz thanks! But I think my system is in such a frozen state that it wouldn't help... it doesn't react to anything, not even the shutdown combos and does not even connect via USB cable to computer.... Anyway we have lots of WiFi here in the air :)